# Issues when using SUBSTRING to trim the first 6 characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named Articles, which suprisingly has a column  named Article, which is the Primary Key.
In this column all articles used to be designated with an unnecessary prefix which I am tasked to remove.

Examples:

1-184-W21TK00032

1-154-MXA0074

In these examples both 184 and 154 designate distributors, they all have a few thousand Articles in this table.

I encountered zero problems when running this query:

```
UPDATE Articles
SET Article = SUBSTRING(Article,7,LEN(Article)-6)
WHERE SUBSTRING(Article,3,3) = '184'
```

I was unable to run this query without a WHERE designation. I altered the final line to switch to the next distributor: 154

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(Article,3,3) = '154'
```

And ran into this error:

```
Msg 536, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function.
```

I have also tried using LIKE in the WHERE line, to designate everything using '-154-' like so

```
WHERE Article LIKE '_-154-%'
```

but this would inexplicably lead to this, as would running the query without a WHERE as I started out trying:

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'aaaaaArticles_PK'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Articles'.
```

Any ideas or suggestions? I'm at a loss. Running it without a WHERE line is now impossible for the thousands of products using 184 have succesfully been altered.

Comment: Don't use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: please just sample data according to your table

Comment: btw--  as to the bigger picture, make sure the Article without the prefix is really unique before you finish the modifications (if you haven't already).  I'm concerned because of the last error. If it isn't unique still, consider adding an Identity integer or the like first, then move the primary key over to that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because `LEN(Article)` is less than 6 for at least 1 row which means you are passing a negative value into the `SUBSTRING`. Filter them out using `WHERE LEN(Article) > 6`

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not the WHERE you're changing that is the issue.

There are probably rows for "154" where the other SUBSTRING fails.
That is, there are probably (Len(Article) - 6) < 0.

Search for that to confirm and then add a CASE or such to manage it.

Comment: Haha, well you can have +1 from me too :)

Comment: Thanks, solved it combining all the answers I got and figuring out my own sillyness. Old remnants with 0 items in stock where causing the duplicates and were easily removed, and as you and DavidG both pointed out there were some Articles with LEN(Article) < 6. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RIGHT(article,LEN(article)-6)
```

Instead of `Substring`, this will select everything to the right of the first 6 characters.

Comment: Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

Comment: Then you probably need to weed out the negatives like @DavidG said